# Why can't I connect to this websocket?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

Having great difficulty getting a response, even a reassuring error response, after attempts to connect to Coinfloor's websocket API. Docs here: https://github.com/coinfloor/API/blob/master/WEBSOCKET-README.md

> 'Commands, replies, and notifications traverse the WebSocket in text
>   frames with JSON-formatted payloads.'

Here is my attempt:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = 'api.coinfloor.co.uk'
port = 443
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname('api.coinfloor.co.uk')
payload = '{"method": "WatchTicker","base": int("0xF800", 16),"counter":int("0xFA20",16),"watch":True}'
s.connect((server_ip, port))
s.sendall(payload.encode('utf-8'))
result = s.recv(4096)
print(result)
```

It just returns this:

```
b''
```

i.e. an empty byte string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sockets and WebSocket are completely different things. AF_INET/SOCK_STREAM socket is a facility that uses TCP to communicate to the remote peer. On the other hand, WebSocket is a binary protocol that

1. Works on the top of TCP or TLS.
2. Has to perform HTTP handshake before data exchange.

Since WebSocket is a rather complex protocol ([see the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)), your best course of action is to find a WebSocket library and use it instead of trying to implement the protocol starting from TCP.