# Where to find a non-blocking python websocket implementation (single threaded)

Tags: python, websocket, nonblocking

In the python [`websocket` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket), the `recv` method will wait (block) until data is available and then return it.

I want a **single-threaded** implementation where `recv` will return `None` when there is no data available, else it will return the data. Or perhaps an implementation with a boolean `has_data` method.

Comment: Are you asking about sockets or WebSocket? You list both tags, but they are completely different things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731012/why-cant-i-connect-to-this-websocket/48740790#48740790

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 only websockets

Comment: Python standard library doesn't have `websocket` module. Which library are you using? Are you sure you don't mean `socket` stdlib module? `recv` is a typical function name for sockets, but not for WebSocket protocol.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 I'm using the `websocket (0.2.1)` package located here `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket`